# Bias imbalance in learning algorithm

Tags: regression, ridge-regression, intercept, bias-correction

I have the following model:

$$
q^\star = argmin\{\sum_{i=1}^n (y_i q^T x_i)+ λ\|q\|^2_2\}
$$

where each $x_i$ is a sample of a $p$ dimensional feature vector. As it is common to do, I have encoded the bias (intercept) as one of the feature, ie. such that $x_{ij}=1$ for all $j$. All other features are presumed to be on the same scale (they're all standardized).

My question is as follows: is there any theoretic way to deal with the fundamental imbalance of the regularization term $λ\|q\|^2_2$ which puts the bias term to a disadvantage? For example, if the solution is expected to be heavily biased, $λ$ will penalize the bias feature  more than it should, especially if $p$ is large.

I was thinking of sampling a few $q^\star$ with $λ=0$ in order to obtain an idea of the expected scale of $q$, and then apply its inverse to features, before running the model again: $\tilde X = Xq^{-1}$, with $q^{-1}$ applied element wise, in order to help the model.

However this is very adhoc, and perhaps there's some theoretical motivation or state of the art way of dealing with this imbalance.

Comment: Just leave it out of the regularization term altogether?  Alternatively, but equivalently, standardize all your terms - $y$ and each element of $x$ - to have zero mean before the estimation, in which case you can drop the intercept altogether.

Comment: Choose a parameter error that you wish to minimize, and optimize your $\lambda$ for that purpose. For example, see [Appendix in](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20865304)